# iterator type for Template split class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, iterator

```
template <class write_iter> //class for splitting a line into individual words
class Split
{
public:
split(const string& line, write_iter destination)
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    iter i;

    while(i != line.end())
    {
        i = find_if(i, line.end(), not_space);
        iter j = find_if(i, line.end(), space);

        if (i != line.end())
            *destination++ = string(i,j);

        i = j;
    }
}

bool not_space(char c)
{
    return !isspace(c);
}

bool space(char c)
{
    return isspace(c);
}
};

int main()
{
while(getline(cin, line))
    Split<> split(line, back_inserter(words));
}
```

- I want to be able pass any sort of iterator i want:
  *ex: back_insterter(somevector), ostream_iterator*
- For back_inserter, what goes in Split < ?? > split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Split <decltype(back_inserter(words))>(line, back_inserter(words));
```

or here's the full type:

```
Split <std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string>>>(line, back_inserter(words));
```

Instead of having a templated class, why not just have a templated constructor? it would make things a lot easier.

Those `not_space` & `space` functions should be static as well for `find_if` to work. Or move them outside the class.

One more thing: a back_insert_iterator does not need to be incremented. `*destination = string(i,j);` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, the increments are not needed for either iterator. Ye, i think putting this in a class is bad idea, I had split as a function before, and I wanted to see what things i could do if it were in a class. Thanks! I never had the chance to put myself in a situation where i needed 'decltype()' before so this is exciting :) everything works now.

Comment: i also did end up changing it to a template constructor, so much easier.